# How to display ðŸ”´ in JLabel or java

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to figure out how to display ðŸ”´ in java. I am able to convert unicode to show so if I could convert ðŸ”´to unicode then I would be set. I was thinking I could just make a big check list but figure that would cause alot of strain to check.

I am trying to show , but the API call gives me ðŸ”´. My question is, how do I change ðŸ”´ to the red circle other then finding the Unicode string for it.

This is what the symbol looks like

Code to format json

```
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. Can you post some code and explain what you want to actually show? The red circle or the 2 characters in the title of your question?

Comment: I have no code to show cause I don't know how to even go about doing it.

Comment: What API call? Show some code. You may be handling the result of the "API call" incorrectly.

Comment: Its the twitch follower call. The string I get in is "status": "ðŸ”´Sub-a-Ton (16hour Cap)ðŸ”´FamilyRP WL | SASP Kurt Leonard | GTA RP | Sh00t YeAH!!!", Theres not much need cause this is what it gives, no mater what I change in my code, this is all I can get back. I have tried running the call in 4 different online things and its all the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking at the characters with an editor in which you haven't specified the correct character encoding / set.

To use smybol that String in Java, try:

```
String text = "\uD83D\uDD34";
JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
```

Source of the unicode escapes: https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+1F534

(It may still be that your font doesn't have the character, in which case it will probably look like a question mark - better than 4 strange accented characters, probably)

Comment: Thanks, that kind of helps. Dosn't look like there is going to be much of a way to just write a few lines. Might just have to ditch it for rn for performace.

Answer (score 1):

There still remains one problem: `new InputStreamReader(is)` uses the default encoding the program runs on. I would expect the fixed encoding of the `is`: `new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")`